# Can't change name field in register file

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

In the normal auth scaffold there is a 'name' field and I changed this to 'voornaam'. But since I did that it gives me this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'voornaam' doesn't have a
>   default value (SQL: insert into `people` (`email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (****@hotmail.com,
>   $2y$10$MD1lSAS1XyA3tW3MzCE68Oz9zrPDZiq0CLJRo3KEnEC/uI2K8kLui,
>   2017-05-08 16:03:42, 2017-05-08 16:03:42))

It doesn't insert anything into voornaam.

This is my Register Controller:

```
use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

protected $table = 'people';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'voornaam' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:people',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'voornaam' => $data['voornaam'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

And this is the HTML part:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="voornaam" type="text" class="form-control" name="voornaam" value="{{ old('voornaam') }}" required autofocus>

    @if ($errors->has('voornaam'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('voornaam') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show your User Model? If I had to guess you don't have `fillable` for `voornam`.

Comment: Yes you were right that was the problem stupid mistake.. thank you

Comment: Are u using phpmyadmin for mysql ?